# Check if file exists for hidden (.file) files

Tags: bash, terminal

Using `if [ -f "file" ]` works on non-hidden files.
I'm trying to use it for a hidden file: `if [ -f ".file" ]` and of course it returns false (even that `.file` exists).

If I use `if [ -f -a "file" ]` it returns true for **all** hidden files (that is, if 'any' file is hidden).

How can I check if a `.someFile` exists (where 'someFile' is a hidden file)?

Comment: I suggest: `help test`

Comment: @Cyrus Ok, now I feel dumb. It's all there, listed green on black. Thanks!

Comment: `if [ -f "file" ]` will work fine for detecting hidden (but otherwise normal) files. If it's failing, you probably have something like a symbolic link to a file elsewhere; that's not a regular file, so the `-f` test will return false. It has nothing to do with whether it's hidden or not.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, found it (by just trying really).  Need to use `-a` instead of `-f`:
`if [ -a ".file" ]`

**-Edit-**

Following the great advice by **Cyrus**, `$ help test` will list all the test options. Specifically:
*-a FILE        True if file exists.

-f FILE        True if file exists and is a regular file.*

Comment: what if it's a directory

Comment: `[ -a` or `test -a` works in Bash. It may not work in `sh`. POSIX specifies `[ -e` for this. `[ -e` works in Bash as well. The question is tagged `bash`, so `[ -a` is a good answer. Still `[ -e` would be better because of its portability.

Answer (score 2):

using -e works for me:

```
if [ -e ${file} ]; then
   echo "${file} exists even if it's hidden"
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

For people looking for hidden directory check solution, this works for me:

```
HIDDEN_DIR=$(ls -a /dir_path | grep '.dir_name')
if [[ $HIDDEN_DIR == ".dir_name" ]]; then
  echo "hidden dir exists"
fi
```

Comment: -1. So flawed. (1) [Parsing `ls` is wrong](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). (2) A dot in regex matches any character, so `adir_name` will match. (3) `foo.dir_name1` will also match. (4) What if there are two matching entries? (5) Any match can be a non-directory, but your code states `hidden dir exists` without checking the type.